# Github's JIRA ticket integration: add comment

Tags: github, jira

I've set up the JIRA plugin that github provides and it works well, with a commit message like this:

```
I made the thing work! [#PROJ-57 transition:21]
```

It'll do that transition (In my case it's a 'close issue' transition) but I'd really like it to also post a commend to the ticket saying something like "Closed by  via github: I made the thing work!"

How can I make this happen?